# JQuery wait x seconds after document ready

Tags: jquery

following code waits till dom ready

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

what do i have to write to simple let the execution of the jquery function wait for 2 seconds after the document is ready?

i need this to narrow down a conflict between multiple instances of a plugin.

THX

Comment: usually who is asking your question have errors in calling functions depend on another functions inside document.ready, if this is your problem try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008696/after-all-document-ready-have-run-is-there-and-event-for-that

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Wrap your existing function with a call to `setTimeout`, ie, replace your current:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     ....
});
```

with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
         ....
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: It would be cool if there was something like this that did the same thing but said "Loading..." (spins around) and waits till the "document" is really, **really** ready ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$(window).load(function(){});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

I took reference from [jquery forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-why-do-i-need-a-delay-in-document-ready-when-using-the-center-plugin#14737000000174461)

Answer (score 2):

By using [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).

Answer (score 2):

Read about setTimeOut().
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp