# How to show() an id block

Tags: jquery, show

I have this jquery code that *will not* reveal a content block that starts our as `display: none`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {

    $('#anId').hide(); // show section
    $('#anId').show(); // show section
    $('#anId').hide().show(); // show section
    $('#anId').css('display', 'block'); // show section

  }); // end .load()
}); // end .ready()
```

Any ideas of suggestions as to why?

Here's the markup:

```
<fieldset class="formField__marginTop formField__area" id="anId" style="display: none;">
<legend>Reservation Notes</legend>
<div class="formField__optional">
<label for="reservationNote">Optional Notes</label>
<textarea name="reservationNote" id="reservationNote" rows="5" cols="21" class="formField__text formField__textarea255" enabled="enabled" maxlength="255"></textarea>
<small class="formField__tip">Enter any additional and pertinent information relating to this reservation.</small>
</div>
<div class="formField__optional">
<label>Note Type</label>
<fieldset class="formField__list formField__inlineButtons" enabled="enabled">
<label for="reservationNoteType_746440">
<input type="radio" value="0" name="reservationNoteType" id="reservationNoteType_746440" class="formField__list" checked="checked"> Private (Internal Use Only)
</label>
<label for="reservationNoteType_445052">
<input type="radio" value="1" name="reservationNoteType" id="reservationNoteType_445052" class="formField__list"> Public (Customer Viewable)
</label>
</fieldset>
<small class="formField__tip">Choose whether this note is for internal or external use.</small>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Should work fine, could you show your html markup?

Comment: Yes, it will; proof: http://jsbin.com/silepazi/1. (Side note: There's no reason to wrap a `load` handler in a `ready` handler. And there's rarely any need for *either*; just put the script at the end.)

Comment: why have you put a `window.load` handler inside your `document.ready` handler?

Comment: what are you trying to do? it works even without the last .css(..block..) statement cause .show() puts the element to display:block; or static have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/GGQ39/

Comment: markup included @Anton. THanks

Comment: @H.Ferrence Looks like the selector is wrong, it should be `#myId`

Comment: because of this suggestion @Alnitak --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008696/after-all-document-ready-have-run-is-there-and-event-for-that

Comment: @H.Ferrence Don't put a window load handler in a document ready handler.

Comment: can you comment on why it was suggested at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008696/after-all-document-ready-have-run-is-there-and-event-for-that @JasonP? just so I understand...thanks

Comment: @H.Ferrence that didn't suggest wrapping one inside the other, it suggested doing them one _after_ the other.

Comment: @Alnitak The second answer does suggest nesting them. Just saw that.

Comment: but look at [at]Ian's answer -- the one with 16 up-votes. I was following it to get some of my code to work.

Comment: @H.Ferrence That seems to be a way to execute some code only after all document ready handlers have completed. I don't think that's relevant for your issue.

Comment: @H.Ferrence your code appears valid, and others have apparently tried it out successfully.  Check your JS console for errors.

Comment: i did that already and nothing appears in the console viewport. that is what is so frustrating about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use only one of this handlers `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load`
and your script should work fine.

note that the `$(window).ready` run before the `$(document).load()`.

Comment: ok, I will try it @JefferyThaGintoki -- I use it because of what I found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008696/after-all-document-ready-have-run-is-there-and-event-for-that

Comment: @JasonP sorry dude i was wrong yep the `ready` statment run after the page loads while the `load` statement run when all the page contents loads.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you've placed a `window.load` event inside a `document.ready` event. `window.load` should happen after `document.ready` so it will never fire. `document.ready` is better for this kind of effect because it fires when the DOM is ready for action.

Remove the `$(window).load(function() {` part and corresponding `});` and your code should work.

Edit:

The `window.load` event will fire when the `window` object has finished loading. You can actually attach a `load()` event to anything, so you can fire it when an image has finished loading or similar. Further details are available here:

https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

The `document.ready` event will fire when the DOM is fully loaded - this is generally the point when the page is ready to accept manipulation by JavaScript. As @Jason P pointed out, this is in fact before `window.load` because that event fires when everything in the page has finished loading. There are more details here:

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

A practical example would be a simple page with a really big image in it which takes a few seconds to load. The `document.ready` event will fire when the DOM has been constructed by the browser, but the `window.load` function will only fire after the image has loaded so this could be a few seconds after the page has been displayed.

Comment: I did it becuase of what I found T http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008696/after-all-document-ready-have-run-is-there-and-event-for-that @edcs

Comment: Just realised that - I remember having a problem before where I needed to use window.load instead of document.ready because I needed to know the size of an image. Sorry!

Comment: I'm not an advanced client-side scripter so I am following others suggestions to get my stuff too work. I am confused as to why it works...