# jQuery $(document).ready(function () preloads popups, how to prevent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I need help with my webpage loading time. I use peaces of `javascript` to load external links in an overlay within my page, which i start by clicking. Now i recognized very slow loading times and all external links being loaded when i connect to my single page url.

I guess its the reason of the parameter `$(document).ready(function ()`, which i use for the overlay.

My question is: can i change the parameter to not preload the internal stuff.

Comment: yes you can. Now the actual answer might depend on what you want to do instead of loading on ready. Any fiddle you can share?

Comment: use a different selector? `$('button').click(function{var popups = loadThatPops();});`  or something like that

Answer (score 0):

There's an event you can use that runs after $(document).ready() - it's called $(document).load(). Use that instead and it should work.

Here's another SO answer on that: [After all $(document).ready() have run, is there an event for that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008696/after-all-document-ready-have-run-is-there-an-event-for-that)